# Is the resistivity of all (conducting) alloys more than that of all (conducting) metals?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Is the resistivity of all (conducting) alloys more than that of all (conducting) metals?
I have read it in some places but then I thought of solder.

Comment: Which alloys are you thinking of that aren’t metals?

Comment: I mean alloys and pure metals. like the resistivity of copper is 1.62*10 raised to power -8 and in constantan, it is 49*10 raised to power -6. so is the resistivity of all alloys more than metals

Comment: But, in general an alloy has increased resistivity because of increased scattering off the ‘different’ atoms in the lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead is an elemental metal. Its resistivity is about $1.9\times10^{-7}\ \Omega m$.

${\rm Sn_{96.5} Ag_3 Cu_{0.5}}$ is a commonly used solder alloy (usually called "SAC305" when used as a solder), and its resistivity is about $1.3\times10^{-7}\ \Omega m$. ([source](http://alasir.com/reference/solder_alloys/))

So there's one example of an alloyed metal and an elemental metal with higher resistivity.

If you meant to ask, do all metallic alloys have higher resistivity than their component elemental metals, then consider lead ($\rho=1.9\times10^{-7}\ \Omega m$) and ${\rm Sn_{63}Pb_{37}}$ with resistivity of about $1.45\times10^{-7}\ \Omega m$.